# Easiest way to query oracle database

Tags: asp.net, sql, database, oracle, visual-studio

i need to interact with an oracle database,i usually use toad but i need to simplify some operations.

i'd like to have forms and buttons to launch custom query

EX

have a button "username" and a button "start" so when i press the button ,the program will do some checks whit ifs and cases and then some insert or update

web page or windows application i don't care as long its "easy" to do

i've tried visual basic but i cant understand how to do updates and inserts

Thank you

Comment: ColdFusion is easy, but you have to buy it.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can try every language that .NET framework supports (even F#), but most popular way is to use C# with .NET.

There are a lot of books and manual online abut connecting .NET to DB. Also try reading about LINQ.

Comment: the project i have in mind i fairly simple,digging into c# seems to much complicate to me,i wish there were an easier solution

Comment: No, it's basically around 15 lines of code. Here you have a nice example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9348148/proper-way-to-make-a-connection-and-query-to-a-sql-server-express-database

Comment: i tried follow that example but its for sql server won't work with oracle db

Answer (score 0):

You may strat by looking on the net if there is an easy code that it could help you on your needs.

You can always try paste some code of your mine here so ppl will help you.

Answer (score 0):

IF you managed to make calls to Oracle from VB or the other languages that you are using, but you are having trouble with specific commands, you could wrap them in PL/SQL procedures or packages.
Here's a simple example:

```
create or replace procedure updateuser(p_user in varchar2) as
    --here you can declare local stored procedure variables and you can already give some starting value if you want
    somevariable number := length(p_user) + 1;
    someothervariable varchar2(10);
begin
    --some useless code just to show you basic usage:
    someothervariable := '(' || p_user || ')';
    --Your update or insert statement:
    UPDATE sometable
    SET somecolumn = someothervariable
    where username = p_user;
    commit;
end;
```

To call it from your VB, you might need to do something like this: (forgive my poor knowledge of vb, the syntax may be all wrong):

```
myvbsub "begin updateuser('" + vbuservar + "'); end;"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you bit i know SQL And pl/SQL pretty well . My problemi si The code to send those queries to The db